# How to filter 1 document per time period per object key properly with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregate

I'm building a web api in nodejs with mongoose.
The strict goal of the function I'm developing is to retrieve data to draw charts about them. The it application itself collects data from local printers and sents the data to the API (every 10 minutes).
Each of these Scans results in a mongo document containing all the information required about the printer, with of course a field called created that is an isodate field representing the date and time the document was created.

I need to build a query that given the printer identifiers and a time period needs to retrieve 1 scan per day (in the following case, since it's the monthly variation) for each printer identifier. the first or the last one is just the same. here is my faulty example, since I'm not sure on how to proceed about this.

```
var codeList = [ webAppId1, webAppId2, webAppId3 ]; 
Printer.aggregate(
            [{
                    $match: {
                        codiceSim: {
                            $in: codeList
                        },
                        Created: {
                            $gte: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 30))
                        }
                    }
                }, {
                    $sort: {
                        Created: -1
                    }
                }, {
                    $project: {


                        year: {
                            $year: "$Created"
                        },
                        month: {
                            $month: "$Created"
                        },
                        day: {
                            $dayOfMonth: "$Created"
                        },
                        $original_doc: "$$ROOT"

                    }
                },
                {
                    $group: {

                        _id: {
                            codiceSim: "$codiceSim",
                            year: "$year",
                            month: "$month",
                            day: "$day"
                        }

                    }
                }
            ],
            function (err, printers) {
                if (err) res.send(err);
                res.json(printers);

            }).exec(function (printers) {

        });
```

The result I'm wishing for should be similar to this (for the sake of clarity the following should be the result for a week data, 1 doc per day, for 3 printers)

```
[
 [{docScan1},{docScan2},{docScan3},{docScan4},{docScan5},{docScan6},{docScan7}],  <= printer1
 [{docScan1},{docScan2},{docScan3},{docScan4},{docScan5},{docScan6},{docScan7}],  <= printer2
 [{docScan1},{docScan2},{docScan3},{docScan4},{docScan5},{docScan6},{docScan7}]   <= printer3
]
```

I already have a query to collect the same data as I wish for one printer at a time and here is how I do it:

```
 Printer.aggregate(
 [{
    $match: {
      codiceSim: req.params.printerId,
      Created: {
        $gte: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 30))
      }
    }
  },

  {
    $project: {
      year: {
        $year: "$Created"
      },
      month: {
        $month: "$Created"
      },
      day: {
        $dayOfMonth: "$Created"
      },
      original_doc: "$$ROOT"
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        year: "$year",
        month: "$month",
        day: "$day"
      },
      docs: {
        $push: "$original_doc"
      }
    }

  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $arrayElemAt: ["$docs", 0]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      Created: -1
    }
  }
],
function(err, printers) {
  if (err)
    res.send(err);
  res.json(printers);
});
```

The need to inject some of the data from different printers in the same chart in a single jquery async call brought to try to find a solution, but I'm stuck. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far I opted to complety bypass the solution refining my mongoose aggr query, but I'd really be looking forward for some help in that direction.

Here's how I made it:

```
Printer.find({
            codiceSim: {
                $in: codeList
            },
            Created: {
                $gte: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - 30))
            }
        }).lean().exec(function (err, printers) {
            if (err) res.send(err);
            var partial = new Array(codeList.length);
            var final = new Array(codeList.length);
            var times = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
                times.push(new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() - (30 - i))));
            }
            codeList.forEach(function (item, index, arr) {
                partial[index] = printers.filter(printer => printer["codiceSim"] === item);
                if (partial[index] != undefined) {
                    times.forEach(function (cDate) {
                        var tmp = partial[index].filter(function (item) {
                            if (cDate.getFullYear() === item["Created"].getFullYear() &&
                                cDate.getMonth() === item["Created"].getMonth() &&
                                cDate.getDate() === item["Created"].getDate()) {
                                return item;
                            }
                        });
                        if (tmp != undefined && tmp.length > 0) {
                            if (final[index] === undefined) {
                                final[index] = new Array();
                            }
                            final[index].push(tmp[0]);
                        }

                    });
                }
            });
            res.json(final);
        });
```